# What do we do after missing the 2nd rukuh in Friday Congregational prayers (Jum'ah)

Tags: salat, jumuah

So I live in KSA, and I arrived late at the mosque and I joined the jamat at the second sujood of the second rakat, so after I finished two rakat the one next to me started his 3rd rakat I became confused and out of fear (that my salah becomes void) started my 3rd rakat and then 4th (as stated if you miss the two rakats of jum'ah you must pray 4 rakats).
So can you please help me, I'm a little confused?????

Comment: The three sunni madhhabs who are close to ahl al-hadith will refer to https://sunnah.com/urn/1105550 for praying 4 rak'a, as one missed the jumu'ah and therefore should pray dhur. If I'm not that wrong the hanafis will consider praying only two rak'a maybe explaining this that one missed jumu'ah and jumu'ah is only two rak'ah.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the three sunni madhhabs who are close to ahl al-hadith will refer to ahadith such as [this](https://sunnah.com/urn/1105550) for praying 4 rak'a, as one missed the jumu'ah and therefore should pray dhuhr, this is clearly the view of the malikis and shafi'is the hanbalis differ a bit.

Some more evidences for this view:

> Yahya related to me from Malik that Ibn Shihab used to say, "Some one who catches a raka of the jumua prayer should pray another one with it." Ibn Shihab said, "That is the sunna."
>
> Malik said, "I saw the people of knowledge in our city doing that. That is because the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, 'Whoever catches a raka of the prayer has caught the prayer.' "

(Imam Malik seems to refer to the hadith which one may find in [sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1311740))

> Malik said, concerning some one who was in a crowd on the day of jumua and did the ruku but was not able to go into sajda until the imam had risen or finished his prayer, "If he is able to do the sajda and has already done the ruku then he should do the sajda when the people stand up. If he is unable to do the sajda until after the imam has finished the prayer, then I prefer that he begins the prayer again and does the four rakas of dhuhr. ([al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/502370))

[At-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/4/37) also quoted this hadith and said that most scholars follow this opinion and counted imam Ahmad among them:

See also [this hadith](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=8623&bk_no=85&flag=1) from at-tabarni's awsat in Arabic:

> " إذا أدرك أحدكم الركعتين يوم الجمعة ، فقد أدرك الجمعة ، وإذا أدرك ركعة فليركع إليها أخرى ، وإن لم يدرك ركعة فليصل أربع ركعات "

Which includes the addition: "... and if he didn't catch the rakaÄ'a he should pray four raka'at"

The hanafis will consider praying only two rak'a:
In his "Jurisprudence of the four sunni schools" (Volume 1, p. 530) al-Jaziri explains the hanafi view as follows:

> According to the Hanafis, someone who joins the imam in time to perform any part of the Friday prayer with him will have made a valid start even if he does not join the imam until he is uttering the testimony as part of a prostration of forgetfulness; then, after the imam has finished praying, the worshiper may complete his own prayer as a valid Friday prayer.

Now as I said the hanbalis differ a bit from the other schools, there view has been presented by al-Jaziri as follows (with some comments of mine):

> As for the Hanbalis, they hold that if a worshiper joins the imam in time to perform one complete rak'ah of the Friday congregational prayer, he may complete it on his own as the Friday congregational prayer: otherwise, he must complete it as a regular noon prayer.

So far this is also the view of the malikis and shafi'is too, and the part for somebody whom joined the prayer before the last ruku'u covers also the view of the hanafis.
Now we come to the details which distinguish the hanbali view from the other two:

> In this case, however, he must have performed the congregational prayer during the time period of the noon prayer, and he must have made it his conscious intention to perform the noon prayer. Otherwise, he must complete it as a simple voluntary prayer, then preform the noon prayer as well. (This is taken frome the same source as quoted above, same volume and page)

Also see this Arabic Fatwa [islamqa #209652](https://islamqa.info/ar/209652) and this in English [#22344](https://islamqa.info/en/22344)

According to [this Article](http://www.alukah.net/sharia/0/59298/) the dhahiri school holds the same position as the hanafis!

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not catch the second rakaa, that means you missed Jumaa prayer, then you should complete the four rakat of Dhuhr, that means you pray four rakat after the imam not just two.

Answer (score -2):

You should do Dzuhr prayer if you late for Jumuah prayer, but it's because not on your will want to late.